# Ajax response image element onto Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, canvas

I have an upload photo button on my website which uploads jpeg and png format files on the database.As well as it shows the photo on the website after successful completion.

After successful completion, ajax success calls the *after_success* function which  has the response data as its parameter.

**Function Looks like this:**

```
function after_success(data){


}
```

**Response Data Looks like:**

```
<img src="uploads/56dda66be0181.png">
```

Whatever image comes up from this response I was trying to **draw** it on the canvas.

**My Solution:**

```
var canv=document.getElementById("output");
var ctx=canv.getContext("2d");
var canimg=($('img',data));
ctx.drawImage(canimg,10,10);
```

But this didn't seem to work.How do i get the image on this canvas element?

Note:
Using  **Div** element and jquery **.html()** it does show the image inside the **Div** element.

Comment: You want to draw the image from the response img tag o to canvas?

Comment: Yeah that is what i was trying to do    @Anubhab

Comment: Is any other method acceptable? I mean you could show the image even before you sent the same through a post request giving the user the idea of quick upload and then show success and failure on response - is this acceptable?Secondly, are the other data you get as a response also relevant for the user? i.e. the absolute file path per say? Wanted to confirm these before posting a solution.

Comment: well updated my question.Plus it would be nice if you can help me with method only @Anubhab :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function after_success(data){
    $('#hiddendiv').html(data);
    var img=new Image();

    img.src=$('#hiddendiv').find('img').attr('src');

    $('#hiddendiv').hide();

        var canv=document.getElementById("output");
        var ctx=canv.getContext("2d");
    img.onload= function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
    }
```

This is what i did to achieve the same.Thanks to @anubhab.Gave me a fair Idea as to how to do this.Just tweaked his code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I understand correctly, from response of an upload you'll get an image tag, you want to draw the same image on to a canvas with the id output.

Breaking down - 
1. you gave to get the image url from the src of the img tag you are getting as response.
2. You have to draw it on to output

```
var after_success = function(data){

    $('.someHiddenDiv').append(data);//append the response data to some div which is invisible. This is just to get jQuery to access the element as dom.

       var img = new Image();//well initialize a new image
       //on load of the image draw it on to canvas
       img.onload = function(){
           var canvas = document.getElementById('output');
           var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
           ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);//same as what you have done
       };
       img.src = $('.someHiddenDiv').find('img').attr('src');//get source from the image tag

    }
```

This should work!

Comment: well what it does is that it shows the image inside the div that you have appended and the canvas comes up empty :3.Don't you have to hide the div when the onload has finsihed?Cause this div will definetly show the image.Apart from this canvas doesn't laod the image

Comment: For the idea you gave me. +1 for that. @Anubhab Thanks.

Comment: one more thing `.append` would work only once.If you use the upload button again it won't update the new pic inside the canvas.